# Mockito object as null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test case using Mockito. Below is my sample code:

```
class A {

   Attr1 attr1;
   Attr2 attr2;


  public boolean methodToBeTested(String str) {

       Boolean status1 = attr1.doSomething();

       TempObject temp = attr2.create();

       Boolean result = anotherMethod() && temp.doAnotherThing();

  }

  boolean anotherMethod()  {

      return true;
  }
}
```

My Test Class:

```
class ATest extends AbstractTestCase {

    @Mock
    Attr1 attr1;

    @Mock
    Attr2 attr2;

    @Mock 
    TempObject tempObj;


    A obj;       // This is not mocked

    @Before
    public void setup() {

           obj = new A(attr1, attr2);
    }


    @Test
     public void testMethodToBeTested() {

           Mockito.when(obj.attr1.doSomething()).thenReturn(true);
           Mockito.when(obj.attr2.create()).thenReturn(tempObj);

           Mockito.when(tempObj.doAnotherThing()).thenReturn(true);

           Assert.assertTrue(obj.methodToBeTested(someString))

     }
}
```

However I get Null Exception when it tries to execute `temp.doAnotherThing()`.
 In the mock test I have also tried using `Mockito.doReturn(tempObj).when(obj.attr2).create()` inplace of `Mockito.when(obj.attr2.create()).thenReturn(tempObj)`

However this does not help either.

Am I mocking the object tempObj incorrectly?

Comment: You mean `tempObj`?

Comment: Yes. I have named the mocked object as tempObj in test class and as temp in actual class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `@Mock` annotations be sure to mark your class as using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
    @Mock
    private Foo foo; // will be instantiated by the runner rather than left null in OP question
```